# How to get MySQL to load data from a TEXT column that contains CSV data as multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, csv

We want our users to be able to upload CSV files into our software and have the files be put into a temporary table so they can be analyzed and populated with additional data (upload process id, user name, etc).

Currently our application allows users to upload files into the system, but the files end up as TEXT values in a MySQL table (technically BLOB, but for our purposes, I will call it TEXT, as the only type of files I am concerned with are CSVs).

After a user uploads the CSV and it becomes a TEXT value, I want to take the TEXT value and interpret it as a CSV import, with multiple columns, to populate another table **within MySQL without using a file output**.

A simple insert-select into won't work as the TEXT is parsed as one big chunk (as it should be) instead of multiple columns.

```
insert into db2.my_table (select VALUE from db1.FILE_ATTACHMENT where id = 123456)
```

Most examples I have found export data from the DB as a file, then import it back in, i.e. something like:

```
SELECT VALUE INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv'
```

followed by something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

But I would like to do the entire process within MySQL if possible, without using the above "SELECT INTO OUTFILE/LOAD DATA INFILE" method.

Is there a way to have MySQL treat the TEXT value as multiple columns instead of one big block? Or am I stuck exporting to a file and then re-importing?

Thanks!

Comment: When the files are uploaded to the server, they must exist somewhere on local disk at least temporarily, no? You probably have a script that inserts a row into your blob table and then deletes the temp file. So why not just have that script also do a `LOAD DATA INFILE` on the temp file before deleting it?

Comment: mysql's csv support is exclusively for `load infile`. to tear apart csv data that's already in the DB, you'd be restricted to string operations, which means basically writing your own CSV parser using nothing but sql. you'd be far better simply dumping the text to a file and then re-loading it.

Answer (score 0):

There is flaw in your data load approach. 
Instead of keep each row in a single column, keep each value in respective column.

For example, suppose csv file contains `n` column. Create a table with `n` columns.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS; // for ignoring header if present in csv file.
```